# Envío de mail con Google Apps Script se queda en mi bandeja de salida

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, gmail, google-drive

Realice un GoogleScript para enviar correos para un compañero, funciona perfectamente, hice una copia del spreadsheet que lleva el código y se lo copie en su drive, ahora cuando lo utiliza quedán en mi bandeja de salida los correos que el envía cuando corre el script.

¿Cómo hacer para que el "principalEmail" cambie y queden los envíos en su bandeja de salida?

Cabe aclarar que en esa copia yo estoy como propietario del spreadsheet y el tiene facultades de edición.

Comment: Parece que en el script te dejaste a ti mismo como *sender*. Pero poco podemos hacer sin ver el código.

Comment: Hola Ignacio. Es bueno ver que has regresado a publicar una segunda pregunta. En tu primera pregunta ya tienes una respuesta pero no ha hecho ningún comentario ni marcado esa como respuesta aceptada. Aunque no es obligatorio, es bueno hacerlo.

Comment: Ya he realizado el comentario referente a la pregunta anterior y quedó marcada como respuesta aceptada, soy nuevo en este foro, poco a poco iré conociendo las reglas.

Comment: Gracias Ignacio tanto por el comentario como por el interés en aprender cómo funciona este sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con base en lo que has mencionado, estas usando el servicio GmailApp. Este servicio hace el envío de los mensajes a nombre del "usuario efectivo", es decir, aquel cuyas credenciales están siendo utilizadas para acceder a los servicios, como en este caso Gmail, que requieren autorización.

Para que los mensajes queden en Enviados de tu compañero y no en el tuyo, deberás modificar tu script de tal forma que se ejecute con sus credenciales, por ejemplo, si estás usando un activador instalable, podrías quitar el que has creado con tu cuenta y crear uno nuevo usando la cuenta de tu compañero. Algo más elegante sería que crearas un script para manejar los activadores instalables e incluso ir más allá y crear un complemento. Si lo que buscas es una solución rápida y efectiva haz lo primero.

Comment: He realizado dos actividades las cuales lo han solucionado. La primera fue cambiar la propiedad del archivo, hice propietario del archivo a mi compañero con ello queda como comentas "como usuario efectivo". La segunda fue también tomando tu consejo crear un script que eliminara el activador que había creado con mi cuenta y creara el mismo activador ya con su cuenta y siendo el dueño del spreadsheet.

Comment: var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var triggerId = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("newTrigger1")
  .forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("newTrigger2")
  .forSpreadsheet(ss).onOpen().create();

Comment: Es mejor incluir el código de la solución como una respuesta en particular porque los comentarios tienen la finalidad de ser usados para solicitar aclaraciones, dar consejos sobre cómo mejorar las publicaciones los cuales eventualmente podrían ser eliminados.